# How To Delete String1 from String2 and build a new String2 with remaining string?

Tags: java, string, character

I have 2 String str1 and str2 and i want to build a updated str2 with the contents which character is not present inside the str1 without using inbuilt function of string.
String is as follows:

```
String str1="bdf";

String str2="abc gde fhi**";
```

and output should be like:

```
"ac ge hi";
```

Comment: in which language? and why not to use inbuilt function of string?

Comment: because this is a homework question - and they are being asked to constuct an algorithm...

Comment: Are you allowed to convert the String to a CharArray? Because then you could loop over all the characters and check wether it is in the array or not. Or are you not allowed to use any String.function?

Comment: This is in java, and i don't want to use string inbuilt functions

Comment: Where the trailing *s go from the output?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use the inbuilt way to read from a  string a an array of chars and a foreach loop to remove the included chars.

For c# it would look like this:

```
foreach(char c in  str1)
{
   str2.Replace(c,' ').Trim();
}
```

Of course you could also use indexes and str.Remove() to avoid spaces...

-EDIT sorry I just read you weren't allowed to use inbuilt functions - but reading from string as array is no function - every string is saved in memory as an array of chars - so this should be ok, only got to change the way to remove the chars:

```
String result;
int i=0;
foreach(char c in  str2)
{
   Bool isincluded = false;

   foreach(char c2 in str1)
   {
     if(c == c2) isincluded = true;
   }

   if(isincluded == false)
   { 
      result[i] = c;
      i++;
   }
}
```

isn't verified...but I hope it works :)

Comment: Hey, Lorenz thanks, but i don't want to use string inbuilt function and u say use Replace() and Trim(). This is not my solution...

Comment: look above...edited a way without inbuilt functions, hope it works ;)

Comment: edited again so there are no spaces where there should be none - thanks to Daniel!

Answer (score 0):

```
String removeCharsFromString(String fromString, String charsToBeRemoved) {
    BitSet charSet = new BitSet();
    for (char c : charsToBeRemoved.toCharArray())
        charSet.set(c);

    StringBuilder outputStr = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : fromString.toCharArray())
        if (charSet.get(c) == false)
            outputStr.append(c);
    return outputStr.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Emil, But i don't want to use string inbuilt function. such as (toCharArray()) that you are using in the above code. thanks good example

Answer (score 0):

This is the full example. It's not the best effective you can get, but since you can't use functions made especially for your problem, this should work fine:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        String s1 = "abc def ghi"; // Source
        String s2 = "behi";           // Chars to delete 

        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(s1); // Creates buffer (for deleteCharAt() func)

        for (int i=0; i<s2.length(); i++){ // For each letter in the delete-string 
            for (int j=0; j<s1.length(); j++){ // Test each letter in the source string
                if (s1.charAt(j)==s2.charAt(i)){ // Chars equal -> delete
                    buf.deleteCharAt(j);
                    s1=buf.toString(); // Updates the source string
                    j--;     // Moves back one position (else it would skip one char, due to its deleting)
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(buf.toString());
    }
}
```